# How to Map Strings to an integer using jolt spec

Tags: json, jolt

I want to map a string to an integer using **`jolt`**.

For example;

- *if* the value of **`"state"`** is **`"up"`** then the output should be
  **1**
- *else if* **`"state"`** is **`"down"`** then the output should be **0**
- *else*(i.e. any other value of **`"state"`**) the output should be
  **-1**

Example JSON:

```json
{
  "state": "up"
}
```

Desired output:

```json
{
  "state": 1
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix those constant values with **`#`** notation with sub-objects of **`"state"`** object as conditionals within a **shift** transformation,
and convert the value to the integer by using **modify** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "state": {
        "up": { "#1": "&2" },
        "down": { "#0": "&2" },
        "*": { "#-1": "&2" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=toInteger"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It will convert "state": "1" . Then I applied another operation to convert it to an integer. So, I required two operations.
Is this possible by using only one operation?

Comment: Welcome to the community @JeetMukherjee . In that case , a modify transformation would be needed to add as I've edited within the answer.